# Specify a Send To destination for a LIST?

Tags: retention, send-to-destination

I am using SP2013 on-premise standard edition. On one of site collection we have several lists contains the announcement from different departments. We need to setup retention policy on these lists so that after the announcement reach `"expire date"` (a date field on these lists), the announcement item will be archived to another location which viewer will not have access.

I understand that I can setup "Send To destination" for libraries. But it seems not possible for `Lists`. I cannot find the `"Send to destination"` option in List's setting. Is there any work around? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Retention Policy for your content type. I assume you are doing this for Announcement List so go to 
`List Settings >> Information Management Policy >> click Announcement >> check Enable Retention.` Now you can set retention policy for your items

Comment: I cannot use "Transfer to another location" for retention because I cannot setup "Send to destination" option for LIST. I can only do it for Library only.